# Python multithreading or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Since this is a design question I don't think code would do it justice.

I'm making a program to process and log a high bandwidth stream of data and concurrently trying to observe that data live. (like a production line and an inspector watching the production line)

I want to distribute the load between cores on my computer to leave room for future functionality but I can't figure out if I can use multiprocessing for this. It seems most examples of multiprocessing all have initial data sets and outputs and don't need to be actively communicating throughout their lifetime.

Am I able to use multiprocessing to actively communicate between processes or is that a bad idea and I should stick with multithreading?

Comment: What Python implementation are you using? If CPython, multithreading is only viable for nearly-purely I/O bounds tasks due to the GIL. To distribute actual work among the processors, you'll need multiprocessing. And data can be fed into processes after creation by giving them a queue object at creation time that you push data into from outside the process.

Comment: @Carcigenicate just standard python3

Comment: Then ya, that'd be CPython, and you'll need to look into `multiprocessing` if you're doing work with the data.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ok good I was worried that processes shouldn't be that dependent on each other for some reason unknown to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect the computation needed to process the full load of signal processing exceeds the capacity of a single core, you should consider spreading the load over multiple cores using multi-processing.

If you expect the computation needed to fit on a single core, but you expect many slow or blocking I/O operations to hold up the work, you should consider multi-threading.

If overall performance is an issue, you should reconsider writing the actual solution in pure regular Python and instead look for an implementation in another language, or in a version of Python that gets you a solution closer to the hardware. You can of course still come up with a result that would be usable from a regular Python program.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing and multithreading are two different way of executing code.

In Multiprocessing, you essentially just throw more raw computing power at it (hence the name) as your using more CPUs.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing#:~:text=Multiprocessing%20is%20the%20use%20of,to%20allocate%20tasks%20between%20them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessing#:%7E:text=Multiprocessing%20is%20the%20use%20of,to%20allocate%20tasks%20between%20them).

Multithreading is when the CPU basically breaks the code up into more "threads" of code to perform multiple task simultaneously.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)#:~:text=In%20computer%20architecture%2C%20multithreading%20is,supported%20by%20the%20operating%20system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20architecture%2C%20multithreading%20is,supported%20by%20the%20operating%20system).

For Python, which is normal linear (i.e. it runs from line 1 down to the end of the code in order), threading is better suited for network bound or multiprocessing if its CPU bound.

https://timber.io/blog/multiprocessing-vs-multithreading-in-python-what-you-need-to-know/

So that's the difference, how the code turns out and how the system will operate will dictate whether you use multiprocessing or multithreading.